# What are ways of spreading Islam according to Quran and Hadits?

Tags: dawah

I was wondering, what are ways of spreading Islam (or proselytizing) *according to Quran and Hadiths*?

I am open to any school of thougths. I'm here not to argue, but rather I want to know the gamut of the teachings concerning proselytization in Islam.

*Please cite the Quran and Hadiths (in English please), when you are answering.*

NB: Note that, the question is different from, [How do Muslims proselytize* in non-Muslim areas?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/how-do-muslims-proselytize-in-non-muslim-areas), because that question is asking about cultural things and I'm asking about what Quran and Hadiths teach.

If anything is unclear, please comment before answering.

Answer (score 1):

All praises is indeed due to Allah SWT blessing and salutations upon Muhammad (PBUH) and all his companions, his family members and his entire household.

1. Famous story about Rakana ([link](http://www.ummah.com/forum/showthread.php?58306-rukana-the-wrestler)) and how he accepted Islam. I'm not sure about authenticity, you can look for it by yourself.

   > Rukana ibn Abdu Yazid was the strongest among the Quraysh and one day
   >   he met the Prophet Muhammad in one of the side streets of Mecca alone.
   >
   > 'Rukana', he said, 'why won't you fear God and accept my preaching?'
   >
   > 'If I knew what yoy say is true I would follow you', he replied.
   >
   > The Prophet then asked Rukana if he would recognis ethe truth if the
   >   Prophet could throw him. (The significane here is that Prophet
   >   Muhammad was 50 years old, and Rukana was not only young, but the
   >   strongest man of the Quraysh).
   >
   > When Rukana said yes, they began to wrestle. And when the Prophet got
   >   a firm grip of him, he threw him to the ground, he being unable to
   >   offer and firm resistance.
   >
   > 'Do it again Muhammad' he said, and he did it again.
   >
   > 'This is extraordinary, you can really throw me!'
   >
   > Prophet Muhammad replied,'I can show you something more wonderful than
   >   that if you wish. I will call that tree, and it will come to me'.
   >
   > Rukana said, 'Call it'.
   >
   > The Prophet called the tree and it moved until it was standing in
   >   front of him. Then he said, 'Return to your place' and it moved back
   >   to where it was.
   >
   > [Ibn Ishaque, The Life of Muhammad, pp 178-9]
2. Secondly, remember story of accepting Islam by Khalid ibn al-Walid. He was amazed by the prayer in the danger (while half of people go in sujood and at this time the other half is standing).

So the idea of these stories is the following. If you are talking to wrestler, make dawah by wrestling, if you are talking to trader make dawah by means of islamic law on finance if you are talking to scientist make dawah by scientific statements in Quran. And also speak truth about Islam because there is nothing shameful in Allah's law and His religion.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to preach 'my religion is better than yours'.  Your own conduct in life and living by the great ethics of Islam you will have people coming to you asking about your beliefs etc.  Remember the Quran respects all religions.